# How to use a "#" in a shellscript

Tags: bash

How can I use a #-symbol in a shellscript and prevent that everyting beyond that is interpreted as a comment? I've written a IRC-bot in java and I want to give a channel-name with the beginning hash included.

Answer (score 6):

Just quote it or backslash it:

```
echo '# not a comment'
echo "#" not a comment
echo \# not a comment either
```

Comment: Using a backslash is called 'escaping' the character. You need to pass the literal hash mark, instead of having the shell interpret it, so you need to escape the hash symbol.